# Layout for many independent navigation in a section of a webapp

Tags: navigation, layout, data, cards

There are many sub section in my project and I am not able to find right pattern for the layout the user navigates into the section from side navigation bar and then there are close to 25 sub sections. What can be the right approach for the navigating to these sections?

I have thought of two patterns:

1. Cards for 25 individual sections as they.
2. Present them in a list/data grid kind of view.

Please suggest if any one of these is right or is there any better approach for these.

Comment: How about multiple navigation drawers? First for section, second for subsections etc.  If each subsection has a considerable amount of data to show, it should give you enough space to show it.